# How to clear an optional foreign key in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, nullable, one-to-one, savechanges

I've got an optional 1:1 relationship between two entites. When I set them like so its fine:

`entity.Role = roleObject;`

I can then run _context.SaveChanges() and it will update in the DB. I can update it to a new value fine, but I'm struggling to remove it. If I set:

`entity.Role = null;`

It just sets it back to what it was previously when I call SaveChanges(). I've checked in the DB and the foreign key constraint is properly set to nullable. Anyone know what basic thing I'm missing?

Comment: Is `entity` attached to the context? Does it have explicit FK property?

Comment: Its attached to the context. Nothing has been set explicitly from what I can see (it was developed by someone else), but the FK relationship has generated correctly in the DB

Comment: But at least `entity` is the dependent (the one who has FK in database) of the relationship, right?  What EF Core version  are you using? Can you post a small reproducer that we can copy/paste and run?

Answer (score 0):

You have to try entity.RoleId = null instead of entity.Role = null;

Comment: I did think to try that, but... it doesn't have an id property explicitly declared in the entity class. EF has generated one in the DB though.

Comment: Just add it to entity class. But the fastest way is to use EF Power Tools that can generate all EF classes from DB.